# My C++ database class appears to be leaking memory

Tags: c++, templates

I made a database class to basically hold the hash of kvp id to pointer. Here is the class:

```
#ifndef _DATABASE_H_
#define _DATABASE_H_

#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>

using std::vector;
using std::list;
using std::map;
using std::pair;

template <class T>
class Database
{
public:
    Database();
    virtual ~Database();

    virtual T* operator[](int itemID);

    virtual int addItem(T* newItem);
    virtual int addItem(T* newItem, int itemID);
    virtual bool deleteItem(int itemID);
    virtual T* removeItem(int itemID);          //removes from database but leaves item in memory
    virtual T* getItem(int itemID);
    virtual const T* getItem(int itemID) const;

    virtual void clear();

    virtual int numItems() const;

    virtual int size() const;

private:
    typedef map<int, T*> ContainerType;

    ContainerType data;
    unsigned int numItems_;
};

template <class T>
Database<T>::Database()
{
}

template <class T>
Database<T>::~Database() 
{
    this->clear();
}

template <class T>
T* Database<T>::operator [](int itemID)
{
    return data[itemID];
}

template <class T>
int Database<T>::addItem(T* newItem)
{
    if(newItem == NULL)
        return -1;

    int id = static_cast<int>(data.size());
    pair< ContainerType::iterator, bool> result = data.insert( ContainerType::value_type(id, newItem) );

    ++numItems_;

    return (*(result.first)).first;
}

template <class T>
int Database<T>::addItem(T* newItem, int itemID)
{
    if(newItem == NULL)
        return -1;

    data[itemID] = newItem;
    ++numItems_;

    return itemID;
}

template <class T>
T* Database<T>::getItem(int itemID)
{
    if(itemID < 0 || itemID >= size())
        return NULL;

    return data[itemID];
}

template <class T>
const T* Database<T>::getItem(int itemID) const
{
    if(itemID < 0 || itemID >= size())
        return NULL;

    ContainerType::const_iterator i = data.find(itemID);
    if(i == data.end())
        return NULL;
    
    return (*i).second;
}

template <class T>
void Database<T>::clear()
{
    ContainerType::iterator i;
    for(i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); ++i)
    {
        T* item = (*i).second;

        delete item;
        item = NULL;
    }

    numItems_ = 0;
}

template <class T>
bool Database<T>::deleteItem(int itemID)
{
    T* item = data[itemID];

    if(item)
    {
        delete item;
        data[itemID] = NULL;
        data.erase(itemID);
        return true;
    }
    --numItems_;

    return false;
}

template <class T>
T* Database<T>::removeItem(int itemID)
{
    if(itemID < 0 || itemID > size()-1)
        return NULL;

    T* item = data[itemID];
    data[itemID] = NULL;
    data.erase(itemID);

    --numItems_;

    return item;
}

template <class T>
int Database<T>::numItems() const
{
    return numItems_;
}

template <class T>
int Database<T>::size() const
{
    return static_cast<int>(data.size());
}

#endif
```

It mostly works but it appears to be leaking memory and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: `#define _DATABASE_H_` That name is reserved for the language implementation. By defining it, the behaviour of your program will be undefined. You should use another header guard.

Comment: who's in charge to free items? in case you add two items with same id what happens?

Comment: Why do you think that it appears to be leaking memory?

Comment: Without using `new` or one of the members of the `malloc` family to allocate dynamic memory, it's very hard for a program to spring a leak. More likely you're having problems because the program does not allocate any dynamic memory for instances of `map<int, T*> ContainerType` to point at.

Comment: My suggestion would be to replace T* with std::shared_ptr<T> so that deletion of no-longer-referenced T objects is done automatically.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner  std::shared_ptr should be used with care, only after you are really sure your design needs it (to avoid cyclic dependencies). In this case I am not even sure if pointers are really needed. I'd probably opt for storing T's (and move them into the vectors, to let database take ownership, and then return references to those objects where access is needed)

Answer (score 1):

One problem that may make this code look as though it is leaking memory is that `Database<T>::deleteItem` incorrectly maintains the class invariant in which `numItems_` is the number of non-null items in the object. If the item being deleted exists, the member function returns before decrementing `numItems_`.

`Database<T>::removeItem` on the other hand gets it right. In general a style problem I see with this code is that the deletion logic is repeated in too many places, which leads to bugs like this. Try implementing `deleteItem` in terms of `removeItem`: make delete remove the item and then delete it. Then use `deleteItem` everywhere where you delete e.g. in `clear()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you require the database to call `delete item` in some cases, you need to ensure you don't overwrite items:

1. `addItem(T*)`: generates `id` from `data.size()`, this is not guaranteed to be unique. E.g. the sequence `addItem(ptr1)`,  `addItem(ptr2)`, `deleteItem(0)`, `addItem(ptr3)` will give `ptr3` the same `id` as `ptr2`, and overwrites it.
   Suggestion: `int id = data.empty() ? 0 : data.rbegin()->first + 1;`. Basically this looks at the largest `id` in the map and increases it by 1.
2. `addItem(T*,int)`: does not check if it overwrites existing element. If it overwrites one, shouldn't it delete the original item?
3. `deleteItem(int)`: does `T* item = data[id]`. If `id` does not exist that will return `nullptr`, however it will also add an element `(id,nullptr)` to your map.